# Decomposition of a positive integer

Tags: calculus

Suppose you have a non negative integer K and you want to decompose it into a set of N non negative integers $\left\{n_i\right\}_{i=1}^N$ such that $\sum_{i=1}^N n_i\leq K$. How many decompositions are possible?

Comment: What are your thoughts on this problem?

Comment: This is equivalent to N+1 integers exactly equalling K, since the N+1st is just the remaining difference. Also, look up stars and bars (the method, not the flag).